# Backticks in VS Code launch config not working to escape columns with special characters in SQL queries

Tags: sql, visual-studio-code

So I have some columns in a dataset that have double colons inside (`LeftSide::RightSide`) and I'm trying to use VS Code to run some spark SQL queries that work fine in PyCharm. But it seems that the backticks are causing some issue when they are used in command line arguments set in `launch.json`. So for example if I have this as an arg (including the quotes):

`` "select `PPCUSTOM::Amount_of_Dwelling_Insurance` from tmp" ``

I see printed out to the log:

`zsh: command not found: PPCUSTOM::Amount_of_Dwelling_Insurance`

It seems the backticks are somehow being interpreted as zsh commands?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is stuck, the solution that worked for me is to add:

`"argsExpansion":"none"` to the run config.